# teste unitário com Json mockado

Tags: android, json, testes-de-unidade, kotlin

Estou tentando criar um teste a partir de uma arquivo json que possuo com os mocks da resposta da Api.
Porém quando executo o teste unitário a variavel stream o retorno é null, ou seja ele não consegue ler o arquivo resultando sempre em falha. Existe algo que eu possa fazer para corrigir este problema de leitura que está retornando null? Ou se existe alguma outra forma para ler arquivos Json e converte-los em classes modelo para fins de testes?

```
@Test
fun testGetHeroesWhenError404(){
    val resulr = readFile("mock_response_successfully")
    assertTrue(true)
}

private fun readFile(file: String): ReturnData {
    val stream = this.javaClass.classLoader!!.getResourceAsStream(file)
    val bf = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(stream) as Reader?)
    return Gson().fromJson(bf, ReturnData::class.java)
    //return BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(stream))
}
```

O problema inicial está nessa linha:

`val stream = this.javaClass.classLoader!!.getResourceAsStream(file)`

Pois a stream recebe nulo causando um `NullPointerException`